# Why can't I access a folder I am the owner of?

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, centos

I am running a CentOS vm in EC2. I ssh as ec2-user, and want to create a log folder for my application that I am about to deploy:

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/search-api
sudo chown ec2-user /var/log/search-api
```

Now I am running `ls` on the folder and getting `Permissions denied`:

```
[ec2-user@box_name ~]$ ls /var/log/search-api
ls: cannot access /var/log/search-api: Permission denied
```

Same happens when I try to write a file into that folder:

```
[ec2-user@box_name ~]$ echo 'test' > /var/log/search-api/aaa.log
-bash: /var/log/search-api/aaa.log: Permission denied
```

Why would I not have permissions to list a folder that I own or to write into it?

Comment: What are the actual permissions on it? Try `ls -l /var /var/log /var/log/search-api`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no ACLs, you need "execute" permission on all directories (from root) to access a given file (whether you own it or not).

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS you need to take care also for SELinux labels. They are not just something arbitrary, but if you decide to write nonstandard things into nonstandard places using nonstandard users, you might get burnt.

Please, clarify what are the SELinux labels using `ls -Z`. Also what is in your audit log related to AVCs.